# Trouble Running Ipython Notebook

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

For some reason I cannot open the Ipython notebook. When I run the command ipython notebook, I get a long list of statements that I cannot understand and an Import Error in the last line of the list. I am almost sure that I installed IPython entirely. I did it using pip. To check that it installed properly, I simply checked its version.
Here is the output of the cmd window.

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>ipython --version
3.2.0
C:\Python27\Scripts>ipython notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
  "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "C:\Python27\Scripts\ipython.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 120, in
start_
python
return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line
573,
in launch_instance
app.initialize(argv)
File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75,
n catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 321, in
nitialize
super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75,
n catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 369,
i
initialize
self.parse_command_line(argv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 316, in
arse_command_line
return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75,
n catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 
471,
in parse_command_line
return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75,
n catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line  
402,
in initialize_subcommand
subapp = import_item(subapp)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\importstring.py", line 42,
n import_item
module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\html\notebookapp.py", line 30,  
in
<module>
check_for_zmq('13', 'IPython.html')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\zmqrelated.py", line 12,  
in
check_for_zmq
raise ImportError("%s requires pyzmq >= %s"%(required_by, minimum_version))
ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 13
```

Sorry for the sloppy output
As always, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: `IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 13` => you're missing a dependency called pyzmq or you have it and it's the wrong version. I think it's this dependency but not sure: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzmq/13.0.0

Comment: yeah i had to go back and individually install certain packages. for some reason the >pip install ipython[all] did not install everything

Comment: next time use anaconda!  everything installs cleanly!